# Performance in rendering lines, triangles and squares in LIBGDX

Tags: android, performance, libgdx, render, shapes

I am trying to make a game. Game won't have any textures, because I want to change for example color for every line or square. I heard that Shape Renderer isn't efficient and shouldn't be used intensively. My game will be 2D and is for Android.

- What can I do?
- Maybe LIBGDX isn't good for Shape Rendering?
- What should I do?

Comment: You could use a small white square texture and scale/color that to whatever dimensions you want through SpriteBatch to create lines/squares/rectangles. Triangles wouldn't work this way, though. I'm not sure what your best option is if you absolutely do not want a single texture.

Comment: Thanks. I can use textures, but I think it doesn't make a sense that use of textures are better than simple shapes...

Answer (score 0):

To answer, "What should I do?", ShapeRenderer can take you a long way. Try it, [look at the source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.java) to understand how it works, measure its performance, and if it doesn't perform well enough then roll your own solution.